# How Can i redirect url to another url with the .htaccess in cpanel

Tags: django, python-3.x, .htaccess, whmcs

I want to redirect mysite.com/index.php to  mysite.com/clientarea.php using .htaccess does not work for me help out.
with simple code.
I have tried several time and finally the site is not available

> Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error, it appears you're redirecting to a different hostname than mysite.com - I assume unintentionally.

If you can post your .htaccess code, the solution may be easy to provide.